# Filling an Excel file with openpyxl

Tags: python, json, excel, dictionary, openpyxl

I am trying to fill an excel file with data from a JSON file.

JSON file has the following format:

```
"checklist": {
    "0": {
        "Verdict": "",
        "Issue description": "",
        "Due date": "",
        "Resolution": ""
    }, 
    "1": ....
}
```

and it has a lot of dictionaries within following that format.

Excel file has a header on the first row and the keys of that dictionary on the cols of the second row.

I need to fill the rows of the Excel file with the data contained in the JSON file using the dictionaries that contain a verdict value equal to 'FAIL', 'NC' or 'ISSUE'.

My python code looks like:

```
wb = load_workbook("template.xlsx")
ws = wb['Sheet1']
verdict = ['FAIL', 'NC', 'ISSUE']
for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=3):
    for key in input_data['checklist']:
        if input_data['checklist'][key]['Verdict'] in verdict:
            row[1].value = input_data['checklist'][key]['Issue description'] 
            row[2].value = input_data['checklist'][key]['Due date']
            row[3].value = input_data['checklist'][key]['Resolution']
wb.save('file.xlsx')
```

The problem I have is that the Excel file is filled with the same values in a lot of rows, instead of just one row for each matching dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a problem because you're using a nested loop: for each row, you're looping over the checklist again, which is why you see the same values in each row. With tasks like this you can use zip to loop over multiple items in parallel, assuming they have the same length, or using ziplongest if you know that one list is longer. This is especially important with iter_rows() in openpyxl because, if the worksheet is new, it will soon be exhausted. In such cases, it's easier to use ws.append() instead.

With nested data structures, it is also often useful to use temporary variables so that long, and error-prone lookups.

So, convert your checklist dictionary into something list-like:

```
checklist = input_data['checklist']) # remove one level
for key, values in sorted(checklist.items()):
     if values['Verdict'] in verdict:
         row = values['Issue description'], values['Due date'], values['Resolution']
         ws.append(row)
```

On a new workheet you can advance to the third row by adding two empty ones first:

```
ws.append([])
ws.append([])
```

(Similarly, you can pad rows that you do add with `None` in case you want to insert, say, from column C padding = [None]*2 rather than A.)

Otherwise, if you are working with an existing sheet you will need to set the rows manually.

```
for (idx, item), row in zip(sorted(checklist.items()), ws.iter_rows(min_row=3, max_col=3, max_row=len(checklist)+3)):
   for cell, key in zip(row, ['Issue description', 'Due date', 'Resolution']):
       cell.value = item[key]
```

However, as you have a conditonal step this could lead to blank rows where the condition was not met. In this case you can either create your own counter – which is inadvisable as "off by 1" errors are among the most common in the world and particularly in openpyxl, where we use 1-based indexing. The better alternative here is to filter the results before you start adding the rows

```
filtered = [(key, value) for key, value in sorted(checklist.items()) if value['Verdict' in verdict]
```

NB the code here is illustrative only to show how to solve your problem by making the most of Python and the openpyxl API. I don't have access to your data and have not checked for typos, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I understand your approach and it seems to be the best one. However, this line throws an error:

cell.value = item[key]

TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: Sounds like you're using the second approach. You can easily check what `item` is in a print statement and adjust the code accordingly. It's probably just the key of the dictionary. I'll update my code accordingly.

Comment: Second approach is working perfect for me. Thank you so much!